# Search Reg for word and delete

Tags: powershell

Morning all!

Looking for some help in a powershell script to search for a word and delete the value (not key). No this is not shady, we have a couple of computers that have WebNavigatorBrowser get installed (its a nonadmin per user) install. I cannot find a silent uninstall so I am trying to automate a dirty uninstall. I have done some searching and testing to no avail

So far I have this:

```
$Key = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Evan'
Get-ChildItem $Key -Include *Web* -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

But it deleted the Key not the values. I need to do both because the key might say something else but the value is it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The property all together.  I have tried Remove-ItemProperty in stead of Remove-Item but it doesn't work.

Comment: Honestly this is just my testing setup.  I am trying to remove WebNavigatorBrowser that several users installed (its a per user setup).  There is no silent uninstall that I found so I have to do it dirty.

Technically I want to search the entire registry (all users and everything) for *webnavigator* and delete the Key (folder) and any properties (string\DWORD) that contain that "word".

Thanks

Comment: Well I have a line that deletes keys with that text working.  But I don't want it to delete the parent key if it doesn't say "*webnavigator*" incase the parent key is a legit key with other stuff.

So I have something working that will delete a key that contains that text but it doesn't delete properties (strings\dwords) with that text.

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining myself well LOL

Comment: Thats the thing it's in any User hive.  I think I have my scanner setup to search and find but it's likely different aside from the SSID.

https://ibb.co/2579sKk

Comment: @DougMaurer correct.  Essetically I want to search the HKEY users hive for ANTYHING that contains webnavigator and delete it BUT NOT the parent key (unless it has that in the name).  When looking around I noticed strings that were in legit keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then you need to get the ItemProperty like you already did, but instead of `Remove-Item` use `Remove-ItemProperty` as shown below.

```
$Key = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Evan'
Get-ChildItem $Key -Include *web* -Recurse |
    Get-ItemProperty | Remove-ItemProperty -Name {$_.pschildname} -WhatIf
```

You could also add an `-Include` to the `Get-ItemProperty` if you want to limit what is found, although it doesn't seem like that is needed in this case.

```
$Key = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\test'
Get-ChildItem $Key -Include *web* -Recurse |
    Get-ItemProperty -Include *web* | Remove-ItemProperty -Name {$_.pschildname} -WhatIf
```

Either of these should work. Just remove the `-WhatIf` after confirming it will do exactly what you desire.

**Edit**

Based on our conversation in the comments, I think this may perform the desired action. At least it should be closer.

```
Get-ChildItem $key -Recurse | foreach {
    if($_.name -match "WebNavigatorBrowser")
    {
        Remove-Item $_.pspath -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
    else
    {
        Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath |
            Where-Object {$_ -match "WebNavigatorBrowser"} |
                ForEach-Object {remove-item $_.pspath -Recurse -WhatIf}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does not work however.  I have 3 properties under Evan\Test that stay.  

The intend here is to search the entire Registry for WebNavigator and remove any keys or properties with that word (PUP).  The above code was just me testing on an isolated key before I blow everything up.

Comment: Can the match contain wildcards?  Many of these results just contain that but there is extra for example "WebNavigatorBrowser.JD7GCJRJ37JT5TSOIPKH4GEIDE".

I'd like it to just search for "*webnavigator*" There are stars before and after buts it's being formatted

Comment: That straight code (replacing $key with registry::HKEY_USERS) worked for some but not all.  Getting some permission issues.  Should be running as a local admin though.

GOD I HATE USERS THAT JUST INSTALL STUFF!!!!!!!!!! "Oh I didn't install anything though".

I have spent HOURS trying to remove this because they cannot be bothered to look for 30 seconds.

Comment: The match will work if that is anywhere in the string. Now I did find that any multi string would take more work as it doesn’t show the value it just shows [string[]]